# Is Plotting textual dataset in scatter plot after clustering the data reflect nature of data?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-visualization, scatterplot

i have textual data points.. (1000+) text documents.. i used K-means to cluster these data, then used SVD method upon (TF-IDF matrix) then select the 2nd and 3d columns in VT matrix to represent these documents in 2D in scatter plot, so after i plotting points and colored them based on their cluster id , i found there are many points are overlapping with others... so kindly i would like to know is there any problem in clustering algorithm or scatter plot do not reflect the correct nature of data, or should i use another method to plotting my data points.

thanks ... attached my result data points in scatter plot where each color is an cluster id. [image]

Comment: Why not the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scatter plot is only showing two dimensions of a high-dimensional space, so it's expected that there will be overlap. That is, some points that are different in n-dimensional space will look similar in a 2-dimensional space.